# OpenCV and JavaCv on Android - detect shape on image

Tags: android, opencv, javacv

I'm starting using openCV and JavaCV and I try to detect shapes on my Image. I want to detect circles. I have an Image as a bitmap (and only like this). I have read that first I need to take my Image as IplImage, then convert it to grayscale and smooth the edges. Ok, so I started doing something like this: because first my image is as the bitmap i creating an object of IplImage (I should mention that everything is happing after pressing the button):

```
IplImage image = new IplImage();
```

Then I'm converting my bitmap to IplImage:

```
bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(image.getByteBuffer());
```

And i should know make other thinks, but I can't, because after pressing the button application is crashing on the first line : `IplImage image = new IplImage();`
I tried to use other constructors like: `IplImage image = new IplImage(size);`but it also didn't work. If some can help me how should I do that (I mean create the IplImage and convert a bitmap to IplImage), I will be very grateful.

---EDIT----
I tried again. And now I'm not adding jar using Project->properties->Java Built Path->... But I'm setting jars inside 'lib' folder. But still everything is crashing when I'm tring to create object of IplImage class. Does anybody know why?

--EDIT--
In my lib folder i have: android-support-v4.jar, javacpp.jar, javacv.jar, opencv library - 2.4.3.jar.
My Activity class:

```
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        IplImage image = new IplImage();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

}
And when I'm starting my activity it' crashing and the log:

```
02-09 12:18:59.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7652): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library jniopencv_core not found
02-09 12:18:59.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7652):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:461)
02-09 12:18:59.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7652):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:557)
02-09 12:18:59.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7652):     at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:448)
02-09 12:18:59.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7652):     at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:372)
02-09 12:18:59.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7652):     at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:319)
02-09 12:18:59.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7652):     at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.<clinit>(opencv_core.java:136)
02-09 12:18:59.207: E/AndroidRuntime(7652):     ... 19 more
```

I can mention that if I tried to define `Imgproc img = new Imgproc();`everything was ok. Maybe I can detect shape (circles) using Imgproc, can someone recommend a good tutorial?

Comment: What is the exception you are getting? can you paste the LogCat output?

Answer (score 2):

You can create the image directly as following:

```
IplImage image = IplImage.createFrom(bitmapBuffer);
```

Or

```
IplImage image = IplImage.create(width, height, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 4); // Change the parameter as you need
bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(image.getByteBuffer());
```

Or load the image directly into `LplImage` object

```
IplImage image = cvLoadImage("image.png");
```

**Edit**:

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438017/android-javacv-dilemma-noclassdeffounderror-thrown-inside-of-method-draw-when), it should solve your error.

Based on your error, it seems that you did not include the native libraries (e.g. libjniopencv_core.so) of OpenCV in your libs folder.

Follow the instruction guide to install and use the library properly as well as the `README.txt` file

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588391/how-to-install-javacv-on-android-and-use-framegrabber)

Comment: Ok. so I tried to set: IplImage image = IplImage.create(100, 100, 8, 4);. But application creashed, the log was: 02-08 23:57:36.745: E/AndroidRuntime(4734): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage. I have import: import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.*; So I don't undersand what's going on.

Comment: Make sure you have all required imports, *in addition* to the static import for constants, e.g.:
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.*;
Also, make sure that you have all the required jars with your app.

Comment: I'm searching, where I forget about somthing, but I cant' find. I add all jars: javacv.jar, javacpp.jar, javacv-android-arm, havacv-linux-x86_64. I also importet class: import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.IplConvKernel;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.IplConvKernelFP;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IPL_DEPTH_8U; But it still doesn't work.

Comment: See this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438017/android-javacv-dilemma-noclassdeffounderror-thrown-inside-of-method-draw-when

Comment: I changed a little bit. Now I'm not adding jars via Project->Properties->Java Built Path->... But I just set all jars inside folder 'lib'. But it still crashing

Comment: You need to post a complete StackTrace for the exception and your class (including all the imports)